# Python: programmatically running "pip list"

Tags: python, pip

I'm writing a bit of code that will report and reconcile differences between two pip-managed python installations.

How can I programmatically get the information provided by `pip list` without making a subprogram invocation of pip?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's possible to get a list of packages programmatically:

### Options:

**A. _internal.main**

```
from pip import _internal
_internal.main(['list'])
```

This will print out three columns with Package. Version, and Location

Note that usage of pip's internal api is not recommended.

**B. pkg_resources**

```
import pkg_resources
print([p.project_name for p in pkg_resources.working_set])
# note that this is same as calling pip._vendor.pkg_resources.working_set
```

**C. iter_modules**

Takes a long time to execute (~300ms on computer w/ I5 CPU, SSD, & 8 gigs ram).
The benefit is that it will have a *far* more extensive list of modules and it will output importable names.

Ex: [python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) is imported as dateutil, but iter_modules will give you the importable name: dateutil

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules
print([p.name for p in iter_modules()])
```

**D. Call pip in command line via subprocess**

The solution to this is trivial and I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader

aka I'm too lazy to do this, good luck! :D

Comment: I've verified A and B and am accepting this answer.  Most excellent!

Comment: I guess the approach with `pkg_resources` is best if you also want to know the package version, as the returned object has a `.version` member containing it.

Comment: The `pkg_resources` alternative is deprecated as an API: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html. New code should utilize importlib, instead.

Answer (score 20):

**Update for Python 3.6 and Pip 19.0.1**

```
> from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions
> p = get_installed_distributions()
> pprint.pprint(p)

[wheel 0.32.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 wcwidth 0.1.7 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 virtualenv 16.0.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 virtualenv-clone 0.3.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 urllib3 1.24.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 typing 3.6.6 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 terminaltables 3.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 ...
```

**Original Answer**

Pip is just python module, so just import it and call `list`:

```
import pip

pip.main(['list'])

# you can get details on package using show:

pip.main(['show', 'wheel'])
```

Ok so there is better way:

```
pip.utils.get_installed_distributions()
```

returns you list of packages installed.

```
packages = pip.utils.get_installed_distributions()

p = packages[0]

p.project_name 
p.version
p.egg_name
p.location
```

You can see what `pip list` is doing from the source code [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/ad577befe1eb7980c988ca6c30e13029c96dd202/pip/commands/list.py)

Also `get_installed_distributions` accept whole bunch of parameters to return only local packages (from current virtualenv) etc. Please see help [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/ad577befe1eb7980c988ca6c30e13029c96dd202/pip/utils/__init__.py#L326).

There is also underlying low level command from `_vendor` module:

```
list(pip._vendor.pkg_resources.working_set)
```

However `get_installed_distributions` provide simplier api.

Comment: How can I get the resulting output?  x=pip.main(['list']) sets x to 0 indicating successful execution, with the results going to stdout.

Comment: There is number of ways given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136611/capture-stdout-from-a-script-in-python however I do not like any of them, because they are all cumbersome, let me see how to call it slightly different way,

Comment: @vittore I could not find documentation for pip module. I keep finding [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). But that doesn't have anything for the module api

Comment: @Cripto Just go through pip source code , as I did that =)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Knowing about pip.main() is also interesting.

Comment: @vittore. Maybe add `help(pip) ` to your answer?

Comment: @Cripto `help(pip.utils)` actually does not list `get_installed_distributions`

Comment: @MarkHarrison `pip.main` makes it trivial to install dependencies from code, but it outputs everything to stdout but half the commands will quit interpreter.

Comment: pip doesn't support main anymore - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main

Comment: and utils and _vendor don't work anymore with pip version 19.0.1

Comment: Seems like pip changed its structure. As of pip `19.0.1` (on Python 3.6, although I don't think that matters), this works: `from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions; p = get_installed_distributions()`

Comment: In `_internal` this underscore that precedes the "new name", is somehow telling "Do not trespass", would you use it in production?

Comment: @raratiru I would, even though it is "private", it seems stable

Comment: Thank you, indeed it seems to be so (they even use it at the [relevant tests](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/a8de4eb49a45035aefd9a122b6d1d67915663d5f/tests/functional/test_show.py#L7)) but it was a change that puzzled me. In the mean time, I used `pkg_resources` from `setuptools` to [gather all the licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753985/2996101).

Answer (score 4):

#### `python -m pip list` (robust method)

```
import subprocess
import sys

def pip_list():
    args = [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "list"]
    p = subprocess.run(args, check=True, capture_output=True)
    return p.stdout.decode()

print(pip_list())
```

As [@Aaron mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/365102):

> The officially recommended way to install packages from a script is by calling pip's command-line interface via a subprocess. [Most other answers presented here are not supported by pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). Furthermore since pip v10, all code has been moved to `pip._internal` precisely in order to make it clear to users that programmatic use of pip is not allowed.
>
> Use `sys.executable` to ensure that you will call the same `pip` associated with the current runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Use os module or system module

```
import os 
import subprocess as su
os.system("pip list")
su.call(["pip","list"])
```

Comment: The most useful answer. But the output of either of these calls is an int, why?

Comment: This would be useful for returning `conda list` as well, but same int issue.

Comment: @VaidøtasI. @MinnegapolisCoder9 use `pip_list = os.popen('pip list').read()` to assign output of the call to a variable. (Same holds for `conda list`) On unix the return value of `os.system` is the exit status of the call.

Answer (score 1):

After testing some solution here that is either very slow, deprecated, or return error in my Python 3.10, I'm using this solution:

> **Note**
>
> This function can retrieve all installed package with version installed.

```py
import pkg_resources

def get_installed_packages():
    installed_packages = []
    for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
        installed_packages.append(package.key)
    return installed_packages

def get_package_version(package_name):
    try:
        return pkg_resources.get_distribution(package_name).version
    except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:
        return None

# Get a list of all installed packages
installed_packages = get_installed_packages()

# Iterate over the installed packages and get their versions
package_versions = {}
for package_name in installed_packages:
    version = get_package_version(package_name)
    package_versions[package_name] = version

# Print the package versions
for package_name, version in package_versions.items():
    print(f"{package_name} - {version}")
```

Example output:

```bash
xlsxwriter - 3.0.9
argcomplete - 2.0.0
comm - 0.1.2
debugpy - 1.6.6
```

Combined with regex to list package name, we can check all installed version from requirements that is actually installed in the machine.

```py
import re

def extract_package_names(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        requirements = file.readlines()

    package_names = []
    for requirement in requirements:
        match = re.search(r'^([\w.-]+)', requirement)
        if match:
            package_names.append(match.group(1))

    return package_names

# Example usage
file_path = 'requirements.txt'
package_names = extract_package_names(file_path)
print(package_names)
```

Example output:

```bash
['numpy', 'pandas', 'xlsxwriter']
```

The two combined:

```py
file_path = 'requirements.txt'
package_names = extract_package_names(file_path)

packages = {}
for package_name in package_names:
    packages[package_name] = get_package_version(package_name)
packages
```

> **Note**
>
> **DISCLAIMER**: This code is written with the help of ChatGPT 3.5

Answer (score -1):

For completeness, here's vittore's `pip.main()` idea fleshed out with the capture of stdout.  Of course using `get_installed_distributions()` is the  preferred solution.

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture():
    import sys
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    oldout,olderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
    try:
        out=[StringIO(), StringIO()]
        sys.stdout,sys.stderr = out
        yield out
    finally:
        sys.stdout,sys.stderr = oldout, olderr
        out[0] = out[0].getvalue()
        out[1] = out[1].getvalue()

with capture() as out:
    import pip
    pip.main(['list'])

print out
    ['awscli (1.7.45)\nboto (2.38.0) ...
```

Comment: pip doesn't support main anymore - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main