# Parse output of pip list / pip freeze in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hello  I have a string like this:

```
AdvancedHTMLParser (8.0.1)\nappdirs (1.4.3)\nbeautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)\nchardet (3.0.4)\nchrome-gnome-shell (0.0.0)\ncupshelpers (1.0)\ncycler (0.10.0)\nCython (0.27.3)
```

I want to split this in a list of tuples.
So that each list items has a tuple with two values, the name and the version (without the brackets).

I was only able to split the string by newline but I don't know how to properly grab the numbers in the brackets etc
Can someone explain me how I can do this?

**EDIT :**
I am trying to parse `pip list local`

```
 def get_installed_modules(self):
    data = subprocess.check_output(["pip", "list", "--local"])
    result = [tuple(line.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split())
              for line in data.splitlines()]
    print(result)
```

I have the project that I cant just split the string but it requires a byte like object...

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Does this come from `pip freeze`?

Comment: If you are trying to parse the output of `pip freeze`, you can do that programmatically though python.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , yes, please see my edited post

Comment: Wonderful, there's a much easier way than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
If you're getting these outputs from `pip`, you can do it programmatically, using `pip.operations.freeze` -

```
from pip.operations import freeze  

modules = list(
    map(lambda x: x.split('=='), freeze.freeze(local_only=True))
)

print(modules)

[['aiodns', '1.1.1'],
 ['aiohttp', '1.2.0'],
 ['appdirs', '1.4.0'],
 ['appnope', '0.1.0'],
 ['argparse', '1.4.0'],
...
```

---

**Option 2**
You could also use `get_installed_distributions`, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120690/4909087):

```
import pip

modules = []
for i in pip.utils.get_installed_distributions():
    modules.append((i.key, i.version))

print(modules)

[('pytreebank', '0.2.4'),
 ('cssselect', '1.0.1'),
 ('numba', '0.36.0.dev0+92.g2818dc9e2'),
 ('llvmlite', '0.0.0'),
 ('yarl', '0.8.1'),
 ('xlwt', '1.3.0'),
 ('xlrd', '1.1.0'),
 ...
]
```

---

**Option 3**
A third method is using `pip.main` -

```
import pip
pip.main(['list', 'local'])
```

However, this writes to `stdout`.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks!

Comment: @user4042470 You're welcome. To be sure, please try them all out and let me know which one _didn't_ work. Cheers.

Comment: Is there also a way to check this for a certain virtualenv? Since freeze.freeze is for the local packages outside the virtualenv i believe?

Comment: @user4042470 Maybe you need to pass `isolated=True` to `freeze`?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no docs on using pip programmatically, so I don't even know what half the arguments do. There must be a way, but I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: All those methods have been moved starting from pip version > 10. I provided another answer below.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer doesn't work anymore with the latest version of pip (> 10.0)

All those methods are now in private packages.
For example the freeze module is in [_internal/operations](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/operations/freeze.py). You can still use it but personally I don't think it is a good idea to use internal packages. They might be moved or changed easily in a new version.

What you can do is to keep using pip cli version, use the `--format json` option to have formatted output and parse this in python.

```
 import subprocess
 import json
 data = subprocess.check_output(["pip", "list", "--format", "json"])
 parsed_results = json.loads(data)
 [(element["name"], element["version"]) for element in parsed_results]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> s = "AdvancedHTMLParser (8.0.1)\nappdirs (1.4.3)\nbeautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)\nchardet (3.0.4)\nchrome-gnome-shell (0.0.0)\ncupshelpers (1.0)\ncycler (0.10.0)\nCython (0.27.3)"
>>> re.findall(r"(.+) \((.+)\)", s)
[('AdvancedHTMLParser', '8.0.1'),
 ('appdirs', '1.4.3'),
 ('beautifulsoup4', '4.6.0'),
 ('chardet', '3.0.4'),
 ('chrome-gnome-shell', '0.0.0'),
 ('cupshelpers', '1.0'),
 ('cycler', '0.10.0'),
 ('Cython', '0.27.3')]
```

Comment: Found a mistake, let me fix it... Fixed; you can retract you downvote now (if that was the reason)

Answer (score 1):

Straightforwardly:

```
data = 'AdvancedHTMLParser (8.0.1)\nappdirs (1.4.3)\nbeautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)\nchardet (3.0.4)\nchrome-gnome-shell (0.0.0)\ncupshelpers (1.0)\ncycler (0.10.0)\nCython (0.27.3)'
result = [tuple(line.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split())
          for line in data.splitlines()]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('AdvancedHTMLParser', '8.0.1'), ('appdirs', '1.4.3'), ('beautifulsoup4', '4.6.0'), ('chardet', '3.0.4'), ('chrome-gnome-shell', '0.0.0'), ('cupshelpers', '1.0'), ('cycler', '0.10.0'), ('Cython', '0.27.3')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Comment: When I try to directly query the data like this and split like so : `data = subprocess.check_output(["pip", "list", "--local"])
        result = [tuple(line.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split())
                  for line in data.splitlines()]
        print(result)` I get the exception `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. What can I do to fix this? I mean data should be string..

Comment: No I use python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Split each line on the opening paren & remove the closing one:

```
self.__all_modules = [tuple(x[:-1].split(" (")) for x in data.splitlines()]
```