# ModuleNotFoundError for monetdbe

Tags: python, monetdb

I created a new environment on conda and installed monetdbe using the following command

```
pip install monetdbe
```

This seems to run successfully

When i start my ide(spyder) and try the command

```
from monetdbe import connect
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'monetdbe'
```

Does anyone have any tips on what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: You might have Spyder started outside of your env.

Comment: Yes, and if this is the case, you might want to have a look at 
[this SA post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120646/python-programmatically-running-pip-list).

Comment: sorry, that was the problem, somehow my vs code was pointing to the wrong env