# How do you find the PIP distribution name of a Python package from the package's name?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to programatically find information (such as version number) about imported modules using:

```
pip show *insert package name*
```

In Python this looks like:

```
subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'show', *packagename*]).decode("utf-8")
```

However, the name that is passed as argument to PIP to find information is not always the same as the name used to import the module.

Is there a way to find the name that PIP uses, from the name you use to import the module?

Comment: You can [find the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086030/can-pip-or-setuptools-distribute-etc-list-the-license-used-by-each-install/55753985#55753985) from [`pkg_resources.working_set`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#workingset-objects) you get a list of involved `module_path` and get allvalid `name` from [`pkgutil.iter_modules(list_of_modules_paths)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules). Then you check if `os.path.join(<module_path>, <name>)` is a directory (equivalent to `ispkg`) or it is a file with extension `.py`.