# License list for Python Modules

Tags: python, pip

I have been looking for a package/api-url or something similar to get a list of (possibly) all modules available for python(2,3) and their licenses. 
  
 
 I used to work with js where you can easily api call [npm infos for js](https://replicate.npmjs.com/argparse) for informations as json about the module argparse (versions and for each version a license).  
  
 
I couldn't find something similar for python. Just [pypi infos for python](https://pypi.org/project/argparse/) which is a html response. I also found packages like [yolk](https://pypi.org/project/yolk3k/) or [pkg_ressources](https://docs.galaxyproject.org/en/master/lib/pkg_resources.html) which list all the modules (+ licenses) installed with pip. They wont display modules which are not installed yet.
 
  
 
Is there a solution which either lists all available modules + licenses or a simple url where I can api call and get a json(or similar format) response?

**Edit:**
So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086030/can-pip-or-setuptools-distribute-etc-list-the-license-used-by-each-install) is similar, but does not fully answers my questions. I have already checked all answers of it (namely pkg_ressources, yolk, pip-licenses, Python Package License Checker). They all work fine for INSTALLED packages. But I want a solution for EVERY AVAILABLE package, like [npm for js](https://replicate.npmjs.com/argparse). I do not want to install every single package to get the informations about it.

Comment: `pip` can install packages from private or nonstandard repositories. (`npm` can too, for that matter.) There is no well-defined list of "all available packages" anywhere. Are you asking how to fetch metadata for all packages from pypi.org? What exactly are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: @Daniel _Are you asking how to fetch metadata for all packages from pypi.org_. Yes I am. _What exactly are you trying to do with this information?_ Lets say I get a pyproject.toml and read the dependencies from it. I can get a dependency tree from the given dependencies.<br>
Now to get the licenses for theses dependencies I don't want to install every single dep.

Comment: Ideal would be something like a update stream of the modules like in npm(https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/follower.md). I could just follow this stream and have all the licenses and dependencies saved in my DB.

Comment: You might be interested in [bandersnatch](https://github.com/pypa/bandersnatch)